# Restore flutter app to it original state when killed

Tags: flutter

Flutter app restarts when the app is killed, I want to save a whole widget and then restore the navigation stack or where the user got to, when app is killed. Could someone give detail example on it using Flutter Root Restoration Score.

Answer (score 1):

you should use bloc pattern its best and easy to manage states

Comment: IF u are going to use bloc, I recommend using hydrated_bloc for your scenario.
"An extension to package:bloc which automatically persists and restores bloc and cubit states. Built to work with package:bloc" https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc